# View Size from Interface Builder coming as 0

Tags: ios

This has confused me forever!

When I size something in Interface builder and give it a width of lets say 200 and height 100. And then I connect that to a property in the controller. When I access the bounds of that view I always get 0. What is that?

Should it not return what I have set in interface builder??

Comment: How are you obtaining the width of the object? Have you created the required outlet?

Comment: Where are you accessing the bounds?

Comment: Yes, also a good question. Are you trying to read the bounds in the viewDidLoad ?

Comment: yes, if you try to read it in viewDidLoad then it will not give you appropriate value, you should use it in viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Yes I was reading it in viewDidLoad. I will try out viewDidAppear and see the bound values.